# Invalid likes count for Instagram Posts in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am using the below function to get the `like_count` and the `comments_count` of user's last 10 instagram posts. However it returns invalid amounts. When I visit the instagram profile and add up the likes of last 10 posts it shows a greater value than the value recorded in the database. I was wondering if I have to pass any additional parameters with the `business_discovery` request?

Any help is appreciated.

```
 /**
       * Get post engagment ratio
    */
    public function getPostEngagmentRatio()
    {
        try {
            $userResponse = $this->fb->get(
                '/'.$this->instagram_user_id.'?fields=username',
                $this->page_access_token
            );
        } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        $graphNode = $userResponse->getGraphNode();
        $userResponse = $graphNode->asArray();
        if (empty($userResponse)) {
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'not able to find instagram user'
            );
            return $response;
        }
        $this->instagram_user_name = $userResponse['username'];
        try {
            $businessDiscoveryResponse = $this->fb->get(
                '/'.$this->instagram_user_id.'?fields=business_discovery.username('.$this->instagram_user_name.'){followers_count,media_count,media{comments_count,like_count}}',
                $this->page_access_token
            );
        } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        $graphNode = $businessDiscoveryResponse->getGraphNode();
        $businessDiscoveryResponse = $graphNode->asArray();
        if (empty($businessDiscoveryResponse)) {
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'not able to get user business discovery data'
            );
            return $response;
        }
        if (count($businessDiscoveryResponse['business_discovery']['media']) > 10) {
            $total_posts = 10;
            $breakloop = true;
        } else {
            $total_posts = count($businessDiscoveryResponse['business_discovery']['media']);
            $breakloop = false;
        }
        $posts = array(
            'likes'            => 0,
            'comments'         => 0,
            'total_posts'      => $total_posts,
            'engagement_ratio' => 0,
        );
        $posts['followers_count'] = $businessDiscoveryResponse['business_discovery']['followers_count'];
        foreach ($businessDiscoveryResponse['business_discovery']['media'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($breakloop && $key == 10) {
                break;
            }
            //bug fix : undefined index like_count
            if (isset($value['like_count'])) {
                $posts['likes'] += $value['like_count'];
            }
            
            if (isset($value['comments_count'])) {
                $posts['comments'] += $value['comments_count'];
            }
        }
        return $posts;
    }
```

Comment: Why you are waiting for seeking result in database? Do some run time debuging by adding `print_r()` and `die()`.  Like before `foreach` add `print_r($businessDiscoveryResponse['business_discovery']['media']); die;` check the ouput then comment that line and check the `print_r($posts); die;` before return.

Comment: @MuradAli it is working fine with the instagram account I have, I have debugged and the like_count is correct for the last 10 posts of the account that I own. This issue is experienced by our customers and I can't login to their instagram accounts to debug.

Comment: Don't you store the `access token`?